# jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a plugin that has this block of code. However i am getting this error

```
   JQMIGRATE: jQuery.event.handle is undocumented and deprecated
```

*Cause: jQuery.event.handle was never documented, and deprecated with jQuery 1.7 (see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/deprecated-event-properties-used-in-jquery). As of jQuery 1.9, it has been removed.

*Solution: Use documented jQuery APIs, such as `.trigger`.**

```
handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
    // Save the context
    var context = this,
        args    = arguments;

    // set correct event type
    event.type = "smartresize";

    if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args ); //here
    }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 50 );
}
```

So, this line will be changed to what?

```
jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
```

Comment: What plugin? I guess `context` must be the element and args the arguments passed into that custom event, so something like this `$(this).trigger(event, [args])` maybe?

Comment: @elclanrs, you are correct. please add as an answer. [link](http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing `context` must be the element and `args` the arguments passed into that custom event, so maybe something like this should work:

```
$(this).trigger(event, [args]);
```

I would suggest refactoring the whole thing to use `on` instead of `bind`. Then you can `trigger` custom events defined with `on` very easily, I don't think using this approach you need to define a custom event so you could make the code a bit smaller.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

you could try this:
     instead of

```
  jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
  to use

jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
```

this will work fine...